# ElasticSearch accented and no accented words management

Tags: elasticsearch

I created an index :

```
PUT members
{
"settings":{
    "number_of_shards":1,
    "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
            "accentedNames":{
                "tokenizer":"standard",
                "filter":[
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
                ]
            },
            "standardNames":{
                "tokenizer":"standard",
                "filter":[
                  "lowercase"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
"mappings":{
    "member":{
        "properties":{
            "id":{
                "type":"text"
            },
            "name":{
                "type":"text",
                "analyzer":"standardNames",
                "fields":{
                    "accented":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "analyzer":"accentedNames"
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
}
```

Assume that some documents are in this set **(EDIT)**:

- {"1", "Maéllys Macron"};
- {"2", "Maêllys Alix"};
- {"3", "Maëllys Rosa"};
- {"4", "Maèllys Alix"};
- {"5", "Maellys du Bois"};

I wanted to have this result :
If I want to get documents named "Maéllys", I expect to get "Maéllys Richard" as the best match, and others with the same score.

What I did is to use my analyzers with a such request :

```
GET members/member/_search 
{
  "query":{
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "Maéllys",
      "fields" : [ "name", "name.accented" ]  
    }
  }
}
```

"Maéllys Richard" has the best score. The documents "Ma(ê|ë|é|è)llys Richard have the same score that is higher than "Maellys Richard" document.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: I get a score of 1.3862944 for Maéllys (best match as you expect) and all other documents have the same lower score of 0.087011375 (same score as you expect). Do you care to explain how the results should differ from what you see?

Comment: Please note that each document name was "Ma(e é ê ë è)llys Richard" that's why you find that. It's my fault I give the same last name for each document. Please see above. Thanks again.